# Defining an exception object instead of a class

Tags: scala

I want to define a throwable to return in case of function failure. I don't want a stack trace or exception parameters or inheritance. Can I just define a throwable object then?

```
object BadParam extends NoStackTrace

def f(s: String): Try[Int] = Try(s.toInt).recoverWith(_ => Failure(BadParam))
```

Is this bad for any reason?

Comment: Yes but it needs to be a throwable so `object BadParam extends Throwable("BadParan") with NoStackTrace`

Comment: [NoStackTrace](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/NoStackTrace.html) extends `Throwable`

Comment: Oh wait, the code works. Not sure what is your question, this a very common practice.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. Because I have never seen this in my practice. Only classes extending throwable. Thanks!